# String location

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Could you help me to find the text (in Launchpad) highlighted in the image?

There is a bug with it in the PT-PT. But we are having problems finding this little one.

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask this.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking - do you want to know how to search Launchpad for bug reports? or how to search within an image for the co-ordinates of some 'text'? What is "the PT-PT"?

Comment: We want to translate the "Ubuntu Store".

But until the moment we haven't find the package that contains that string...

Comment: It should be here: https://launchpad.net/unity-scope-ubuntushop, so it seems the app title can't be translated. In that case opening a but against https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8 may be the only option.

Comment: We've already searched in those packages, but it is not there. The only thing we've found was the scope.. which we are able to translate the others strings inside the "ubuntu store". But the one we want, isn't there...

Comment: And yes, that title is already translated to "Loja Ubuntu", but we want to bring it back to "Ubuntu Store". Store means "Loja" in portuguese. It is only a matter of look and since many others translators of other languages keep "Ubuntu Store", we want ours to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could search everything on your system for "Ubuntu Store" with the command line:

```
sudo find / -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sudo grep "Ubuntu Store"
```

Be sure to read `man sudo`, `man find`, `man xargs` and `man grep` **BEFORE** executing these commands from an untrustworthy (as far as you know) stranger.

Once you have found the **file** containing the string, to find the **package** that owns the file, use:

```
dpkg -S /full/path/to/file
```

However, it might be being displayed as a result of an internet transaction, which would mean the "Ubuntu Store" string lives elsewhere.

What does "PT-PT" mean?

Comment: Why not just `sudo grep -R "Ubuntu Store" /`?

Comment: @muru: Because I'm a tradionalist (computing since 1967), have have found that my `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` scheme is useful in many, many circumstances, and easier than checking which commands offer filesystem traversal options (and what they are), and which commands do not.

Comment: -1 for not learning new things, then. :)

Comment: Really? I have learned new things (like `grep -R`), and found that my method is "better". It lets me feed a humongous list of files (or other objects) to any command that accepts 1 or more arguments. I've used it with `| xargs -0 -n 1 xpdf` to run `xpdf` with 1 argument (the way `xpdf` works), and don't have to worry about argument length limits. Plus, the `-0` parmeter to `find` and `xargs` automagically handles filenames containing blanks or strangeness (the only characters that are disallowed in filenames are `NUL` (`\000`) and Slash ("/")). 'New things" are not always "better things".

Comment: all of which is pointless since apparently you have never heard of `-exec`

Comment: @muru: I don't think I deserve the -1

Comment: `-exec` (I've re-re-re-read `man find`) executes (starts a process) once per filename. If you have many filenames the overhead is significant.

Comment: clearly you have not read the part about `+`. Don't worry about the -1, it's a good answer and people will upvote.

Comment: PT-PT is the code for Portugal's Portuguese; user is trying to translate to this language but it seems the name of the Ubuntu Store scope is not available for translation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,I will try it. 

As Reidotoxo said, "PT-PT" is Portuguese from Portugal that is different from "PT-BR" Portuguese from Brasil.